# When to use const in the beginning and in the end of a method declaration in C++

Tags: c++

When coding a header file in C++ with method declarations, what's the difference between:

```
int getFoo() const;

const int getFoo();

const int getFoo() const;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first function operates on a `const` `this` pointer (that is; a const object that it can't change (or at least shouldn't)).

Your second function returns a constant integer - which is somewhat nonsensical since you can just assign it to a non-const variable and change it anyway. Besides, why does the function care if you change a POD type or not?

Your third function is just a combination of the first two. A function operating on a const object returning a const value.

Answer (score 2):

First one, is for preventing this method changing any member variables of the object. 
Second one, is for the return type (ie: constant integer)
Third one, is mix of both

Comment: The second `const T f() ` or `const T f()  const ` is useless.